# rsync exclude not working

Tags: linux, rsync

I have the following rsync exclude that I am trying to run:

```
rsync -av --exclude 'home/dir/public_html/config.text' root@remote.
server.com:/home/dir/public_html/ /home/dir/public_html
```

I have searched documentation and I believe I am doing it right, but I am obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it figured out. I was thinking of exclude wrong. Exclude matches a pattern "config.txt" not the path. So when I made the following change it worked fine:

rsync -av **--exclude "config.text"** root@remote.
server.com:/home/dir/public_html/ /home/dir/public_html

I hope this helps someone